# Confusion about keras Model: __call__ vs. call vs. predict methods

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have realized that I do not quite understand the difference between calling either the `__call__`, `call`, or `predict` method of a Keras' model.

For example, we have a trained keras model. After calling the code:

```py
# After training.
y_pred_1 = model(X_new)
y_pred_2 = model.call(X_new)
y_pred_3 = model.predict(X_new)
```

I expected that `y_pred_1`, `y_pred_2`, and `y_pred_3` are all the same.
But it turned out that they are not the same.

Could you please explain to me the difference?

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Kabanov,  kindly provide more information regarding this, Maybe a screenshot or a reproducible code. Thanks!

Comment: @TF_Support, turned out the bug was in my code. Sorry, forgot to close the this question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Adding to @Dmitry Kabanov, they are similar yet they aren't exactly the same thing. If you care about performance, need to look in to critical differences between them.

| model.predict | model(x) |
| --- | --- |
| loops over the data in batches which means means that predict() calls can scale to very large arrays. | happens in-memory and doesn't scale |
| not differentiable | differentiable |
| use this if you just need the output value | use this when you need to retrieve the gradients |
| Output is NumPy value | Output is a Tensor |
| use this if you have batches of data to be predicted | use this for small dataset |
| relatively slower for small data | relatively faster for small data |

Please check more detailed explanation in [Keras FAQs](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-model-methods-predict-and-call)

Answer (score 12):

Just to complement the answer as I was also searching for this. When you need to specify the training flag of the model for the inference phase, such as, `model(X_new, training=False)` when you have a batch normalization layer, for example, both `predict` and `predict_on_batch` already do that when they are executed.

So, `model(X_new, training=False)` and `model.predict_on_batch(X_new)` are equivalent.

The difference between `predict` and `predict_on_batch` is that the latter runs over a single batch, and the former runs over a dataset that is splitted into batches and the results merged to produce the final numpy array of predictions.

Beyond the difference mentioned by @Dmitry Kabanov, the functions generate different types of output,
`__call__` generates a Tensor, and `predict` and `predict_on_batch` generate `numpy.ndarray`, and
[according to the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?hl=en#predict), `__call__` is faster than the `predict` function for small scale inputs, i.e., which fit in one batch.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE 2021-12-18**. Please see the answer by @TFer2 below  for a much better and fuller answer.

---

*My own old answer that spots only difference in data types (tf.Tensor vs np.ndarray)*

My bad, it was a mistake in my code.

It turned out that there is no essential difference between these three methods.

The only difference is that `call` accepts only tensors, while the other two methods also accept NumPy arrays.

Here is a toy code showing that three methods are the same:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(2, )),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(2),
    ]
)
model.compile(loss='mse')

W = model.trainable_variables[0]
W.assign(np.array([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]]).T)

input = np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], ], dtype=np.float32)

print("__call__:")
print(model(input))

print("Call:")
print(model.call(tf.convert_to_tensor(input)))

print("Predict:")
print(model.predict(input))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a difference when you use one of those specific layers: `DropOut()` and `BatchNormalization()`. Indeed, those layers act differently whether they are used in train mode or test/evaluation mode.

The difference between `call()` and `predict()` is that `call()` is giving a prediction with training mode and `predict()` with testing mode. The difference between those two is that the prediction won't be the same every time you are using `call()` contrary to `predict()`. Train and test mode are similar to the train and test modes of the `Pytorch` library.

Comment: `call` has an input arg `training` that can be set to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but I think it's important to note that as for Tensorflow / Keras version `2.15.0` (with Python 3.11), the `predict` method causes a memory leak (reported for quite a few years now, see for example https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/call-tensorflow-model-in-a-loop-leaks-memory/19792 or just google "Tensorflow memory leak"), and calling the model directly (aka `call`) does not. This is a graph of memory usage during repeated calls to a keras model, using both CPU and GPU, and the 2 options `call`/`predict`. Clearly the memory usage grows linearly with number of calls when using `predict`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same doubt with a keras_cv RetinaNet model. From what I see, there are more differences between **call** and predict with this model.

**call**() returns 2 tensors:

```
{'box': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 9441, 4), dtype=float32, numpy= array([ ... ], dtype=float32)>, 'classification': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 9441, 2), dtype=float32, numpy= array([...], dtype=float32)>}
```

predict() does non-max-suppression and some other pos-processing, and returns 4 numpy arrays:

```
{'boxes': array([[[ 37.201706,  81.78369 ,  62.617325, 136.692   ], ... ]], dtype=float32),
 'confidence': array([ [ 0.9999949   ...  ]], dtype=float32),
 'classes': array([[ 0, ... ]]),
 'num_detections': array([1], dtype=int32)
 }
```

Comment: Your model is probably a customized model, see : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit?hl=en