# call method in custom keras layers not covered in pytest

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytest

I am trying to unit test a keras neural network that uses custom layers.  When I try and run it through pytest and coverage, it states that all of the code inside the `call` method is not covered.

I don't know if this is due to an idiosyncrasy of how pytest delivers the model to the unit tests or if the `call` method is really not being used in my neural network, and hence something is wrong.

Here's some example code:

**Sample Neural Network**

```
class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_dim, units), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(units,), initializer="zeros", trainable=True)

def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b

def build_keras_model():
    
    inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape = (32,))
    x = Linear()(inputs)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model
```

**Sample PyTest File**

```
from model import build_keras_model
import pytest
import numpy as np

def test_keras_model():
    model = build_keras_model()
    
    X = np.random.normal(size = (100, 32))
    y = np.random.normal(size = 100)[:, None]
    
    model.compile(loss = 'mae')
    
    model.fit(X, y, epochs = 1)
    
    assert model.predict(X).shape == (100, 1)
```

If I test this code in its own directory with `coverage run -m pytest` and then `coverage report -m`, then it shows the line inside the `call` method is not covered.

Is the issue with pytest, keras, or the way I set things up?

Comment: Not answering your question but I noticed that you are training the model when running the tests. I have some work done with testing ML models and I would suggest that `build_keras_model` should save the model. Then in your test you would load the saved model and test that the output shape is correct. The current way that you have done it would cause your tests to be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to explicitly call the `__call__()` method of `model` if you plan to have 100% test coverage. Interestingly, `model.predict` does not seem to do that (at least, not at the abstraction level that you need. It does also use the same method internally). Try this:

```py
%%file test_keras.py
import pytest
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class Linear(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_dim, units), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(units,), initializer="zeros", trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b

def build_keras_model():
    
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (32,))
    x = Linear()(inputs)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

def test_keras_model():
    model = build_keras_model()
    
    X = np.random.normal(size = (100, 32))
    y = np.random.normal(size = 100)[:, None]
    
    model.compile(loss = 'mae')
    
    model.fit(X, y, epochs = 1)
    
    assert model(X).shape == (100, 1)
```

```
!coverage run -m pytest
```

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.12, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /content
plugins: cov-3.0.0, typeguard-2.7.1
collected 1 item                                                               

test_keras.py .                                                          [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 6.46s ===============================
```

```
!coverage report -m /content/test_keras.py
```

```
Name            Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------
test_keras.py      23      0   100%
---------------------------------------------
TOTAL              23      0   100%
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837962/confusion-about-keras-model-call-vs-call-vs-predict-methods) on the differences between the `call` method and `predict` method and [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly#predict).